# SQL Server: compare datetime day with GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a stored procedure that should fetch all records with a date equal to the current date or in the future. 
The dates are saved in column targetDate and formatted as datetime. 
My corresponding WHERE clause is the following:

```
WHERE A.targetDate >= GETDATE()
```

In general my stored procedure works fine, my only problem is if the targetDate equals the current date as all dates are saved as follows, i.e. with the time set to zeros:

```
2014-02-22 00:00:00.000
```

How do I have to change my WHERE clause so that it only considers the date but ignores the time saved with it so that I get any records with the current date even if the time is already passed ?

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Which version of sql server you have?

Comment: I have SQL Server version 2008

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change to:

```
WHERE A.targetDate >= cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Edit - because targetdate also contains time, yes, format both like this:

```
WHERE cast(A.targetDate as date) >= cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Edit - given comments re: performance, may want to try:

```
WHERE a.targetdate >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)
```

Last edit should give you the same result and take advantage of any indexes on targetdate

Comment: Thanks - this does not work for me. Do I have to format the targetDate as well ?

Comment: Not if it's a date field. Is it a timestamp or a date field?

Comment: It's a datetime field but the input is always a date only which is why it adds the zeros for the time like in the example above.

Comment: There is no need to cast `targetDate` to `date`.

Comment: Wrapping a field in a CAST() makes it non-SARGable.  In other words, it kills the ability to use an index and causes a full table scan.  In this case, if the field is already a date-time datatype, there is No need for it (no need to remove the time component when comparing `>= a_date`).

Comment: If targetdate contains 2/22 at 5pm and he wants a current datetime of 2/22 at 6pm to come back that would be an issue though. Because of the inability to use an index though I agree he should probably as an alternative use: WHERE a.targetdate >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)

Answer (score 2):

The following should give you the current date with no time:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()))
```

This should be your final line:

```
WHERE A.targetDate >= DATEADD(dd,0, ATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: The use of the second `SELECT` is a syntax error.  There's no need for the subquery so just remove the `SELECT`.  And change `ATEDIFF` for `DATEDIFF` ;)

Comment: Thank you. That was a copy/paste mistake from the line above; I fixed it.